# cURL unable to get local issuer certificate in Laravel using Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I am using Laravel 6.0, PHP version 7.3.9-1. When saving files to cloud storage, using MinIO, I get this error:

```
GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException(code: 0): cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) at /home/vagrant/code/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:201
```

I already set the ca-cert.pem file in the appropriate php.ini file (downloaded from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) and have appended the ca-bundle of our certificate on the server. When running

```
curl --cacert ./ca-cert.pem  [DOMAIN]
```

on commandline, it behaves as expected. No cURL 60 error whatsoever.

Is there something I missed in configuration? I have also restarted the nginx server, but the problem persists.

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080133/laravel-curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/46080345#46080345)

Comment: The problem with that solution is 1) it will stop verifying the request altogether and 2) it will be overwritten every time you run composer update. I am looking for a secure and sustainable way of solving this problem, as that has to exist

Comment: then you can use `__construct` to override default parameters, please add your code of creating object for Guzzle.

Comment: This is all configured automatically in the Laravel packages, so still the same problem of overwriting changes when running composer update. The problem lies in the recognition of the certificates, not in Guzzle. I have previously gotten it to work using all the information mentioned above, so I know it should be possible without touching Laravel vendor files.

Comment: yes, I understand your point. that's why show me code of Guzzle object creation code. Please add your curl code.